# Rails, HAML, using a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, haml, link-to, hamlc

here's what I'm trying to do:
[image: Example of HAML/Rails thing I'm trying to do]

That `'Request Key: '` part should actually be a 6-digit value, e.g.

> Request Key: [614551](http://#)

And the `'PCN: '` part is similar, it should be:

> PCN: [MEDDAET](http://#)

Clicking on MEDDEAT would open a route that would search on that MEDDEAT value in the `:foo_bar` column.

The code I'm trying isn't working, and I don't know enough HAML to know why.

```
  %li Request Key: = link_to #{@request.name}, request_path(@request.name)
```

and

```
  %li = link_to "request.pcn", :controller => filter_plans,  :q => {:plan_aliases_PlanAlias_cont => @pcn}}
```

As you can se, that code just renders as text, not a link. I'd appreciate help on what I'm doing wrong here with the HAML code.

---

EDIT: This is a HAMLC file. Coffeescript! GRRRRRR.....

Comment: both examples in the answers below should have worked. I think you have error elsewhere on this page. Can you remove this line and check if you still have the error. Also perhaps you can post the stacktrace

Comment: The error appears to be in the coffeescript compilation of the hamlc file, and NOT in the code itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
%li
  Request Key:
  = link_to @request.name, request_path(@request.name)
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: unmatched OUTDENT`

Answer (score 1):

```
%li 
  Request Key: #{link_to @request.name, request_path(@request.name)}
```

Comment: this one, whether I put them on the same line or on separate lines (as you indicate) is giving me `SyntaxError: unmatched OUTDENT`

Comment: In HAML you need to make sure that the indentation is correct. Please make sure that you use two space characters on each indentation level.

Answer (score 1):

```
 %li
   = "Request Key: #{link_to(@request.name, request_path(@request.name))".html_safe
```

this will works with rails

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11024281)

Comment: @LucaDetomi How does this not provide an answer? It might be dead wrong, but it's not the kind of thing we should be deleting from review.

Comment: It was flagged as too short. Please provide details to let users understand "why" your solution could be a good one or maybe the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Here was the answer, because it was HAMLC, not HAML (i.e. it compiles through coffeescript and not Rails, therefore Rails helpers didn't work).

```
  %li Request Key:
    %a{ :href => '/requests/#{ @name }', :target => '_blank'} #{@name}
```